# Distribute points evenly on circle circumference in quadrants I and IV only

Tags: javascript, geometry, algebra

I want to distribute `n` points evenly on a circle circumference in quadrants I and IV only.

As parameters, I have the numbers of point `n`, the center of circle coordiantes `cx` and `cy` and the radius `r`.

I can distribute the points over the whole circumference like using this formula below, but I am looking for the formula to spread them only in quadrants I and IV

```
var n = 5;
var cx = 1;
var cy = 1;
var r = 2;

//I store each point's coordinates in this array below
var coordinates = [];

for (var i=0; i < n; i++) {
    //defining point's angle with the center of the circle in radiant
    //this angle distribute the points evenly over all 4 quadrants
    var angle = ((360/n) * i) * (Math.PI/180);

    //calculating the point's coordinates on the circle circumference
    var pointX = cx + r * Math.cos(angle);
    var pointY = cx + r * Math.sin(angle);

    //storing the point's coordinates
    coordinates.push([pointX, pointY]);
}
```

Comment: what are the quadrants 1 and 4?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadrant_%28plane_geometry%29

Comment: Are cx and cy the center of the circle?

Comment: Shouldn't this line `var pointY = cx + r * Math.sin(angle);` be `var pointY = cy + r * Math.sin(angle);` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here would be the steps I'd take to solve this:

1. find the angle betw. each point `var incrementBy = 180 / n`
2. start angle will be 270º and end angle will be 90º
3. iterate through via

**code**

```
 var increment = 180 / n
 var startAngle = 270
 for (var i = 0; i < n; i++)
 {
     var angle = startAngle + increment * i
     var rads = angle * Math.pi / 180

     var tx = cx + r * Math.cos(rads)
     var ty = cy + r * Math.sin(rads)

     coords.push([tx, ty])
 }
```

**note**

I didn't bother to convert for traditional quadrants (vs JS's y-axis moving downwards).  If that is needed then, after your calculations, just invert the `ty` value.  I also didn't bother to reduce the angle value when it exceeds 360º when you're incrementing back into Quad I.

Comment: What's the purpose of calculating `rads` ?
It's not used as far as I can see.

Comment: Because the `Math.cos` and `Math.sin` functions expect the angle value to be in radians https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/cos

But I forgot to put that in the code.  I will edit to reflect that.

Comment: Yeah, the map markers are arranged in half a circle now. Instead of all over the place. Thanks for updating. I should have looked it up myself though. I kept assuming that `angle` (as per the original snippet) was the right field to pass as argument to `cos` and `sin`. Thanks for updating.

Answer (score 1):

like this?

```
var n = 5;
var r = 2;
var cx = 1;
var cy = 1;
var coordinates = [];

for(var i=0; i<n; ++i){
  var a = (i+.5) / n * Math.PI;
  coordinates.push([
    cx + Math.sin(a) * r,
    cy - Math.cos(a) * r
  ]);
}
```

Comment: It's close... this distribute the points in quadrants I and II, not I and IV

Comment: quadrant 2? top left? there's no way, a coodinate can get to the left of cx, not in that code. Have you copied sin and cos the right way round?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the way to equally distribute objects

```
var boxes = []
let count = 10;
for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
let size = 0.8;
let radius = 3;
let box = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.BoxGeometry( size, size, size ),new THREE.MeshPhysicalMaterial(0x333333))
let gap = 0.5;
let angle = i * ((Math.PI * 2) / count);
let x = radius * Math.cos(angle);
let y = 0;
let z = radius * Math.sin(angle);
box.position.set(x,y,z);
boxes.push(box);`enter code here`
scene.add(box)
}
```

[here is how it looks for 10 blocks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZGlV.png)

[here is how it looks for 5 blocks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTGAt.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
var n = 5;
var cx = 1;
var cy = 1;
var r = 2;

//I store each point's coordinates in this array below
var coordinates = [];

for (var i=0; i < n; i++) {
    //defining the angle of the point with the center of the circle in radiant
    var angle = ((360/n) * i) * (Math.PI/180);

    //calculating the coordinates of the point on the circle circumference
    var pointX = cx + r * Math.cos(angle);
    var pointY = cx + r * Math.sin(angle);



    // Here, we are going to use a boolean expression to determine if 
    // [pointX, pointY] is within quadrant 1 or 4.
    // We can start with this boolean equation:
    // (pointX >= cx && pointY >= cy) || (pointX >= cx && pointY <= cy)
    // But this problem can be simplified to only pointX >= cx

    if(pointX >= cx){
        //storing the point's coordinates
        coordinates.push([pointX, pointY]);
    } 
}
```

Comment: Then I believe I am not fully understanding your question. Are you wanting two smaller circles in quadrants 1 and 4, or only the coordinates that appear in quadrants 1 and 4. Or do you want anything in quadrants 2 and 3 to be translated into quadrants 1 and 4?